# How to secure thrift php client with ssl

Tags: php, security, ssl, rpc, thrift

I'd like to secure my thrift traffic. I read this article which provides step by step guide to secure with ssl: https://dzone.com/articles/how-secure-and-apache-thrift

I'm managing with a php client. I didn't find similar class like TSSLTransportFactory.TSSLTransportParameters to set trust store. Anyone has experience with this?

Comment: Not at home, so I can't test anything or formulate an entire answer, but I did find [this](https://thrift.apache.org/tutorial/php) Thrift PHP guide, which seems to reference the classes you need.

Comment: @zbee Thanks for your reply. I've read the guide too, but it doesn't provide a ssl solution.

Comment: It turns out the TSSLSocket resolves this issue: https://github.com/apache/thrift/blob/master/lib/php/lib/Transport/TSSLSocket.php